# Remove subcategory name in URL

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category, product-urls

I have products in three subcategories

parent category: my-products:

1. subcategory-1
2. subcategory-2
3. subcategory-3

Now the URLs are like:

`http://hostname/my-products/subcategory-1/product-name`

How can I get rid of the subcategory name in the URLs so the are like:

`http://hostname/my-products/product-name`

Answer (score 1):

1.Login inside your admin.

2.Go to `System>Configuration>Catalog>Catalog>Search Engine Optimizations>Use Categories Path for Product URLs - Set it to No`

3.Re-Index Catalog URL Rewrites from `System>Index management`.

Should be done!!
[image]

Comment: This removes everything, does it?

Comment: yes it seems so

Answer (score 1):

not really an answer but more of a question... It may be better for you to keep the catagories but use canonical links for SEO and google shopping purposes etc...

```
1.Login inside your admin.

2.Go to *System>Configuration>Catalog>Catalog>Search Engine Optimization>Use Canonical Link Tags for Catagories - Set it to Yes*
2.Go to *System>Configuration>Catalog>Catalog>Search Engine Optimization>Use Canonical Link Tags for Products - Set it to Yes*

3.Re-Index Catalog URL Rewrites from System>Index management.
```

Just a thought

Comment: More of a suggestion... than a question. ;^) It's how Magento is intended to be used. Most of the SEO panic over duplicate content is taken care of with the canonicals. Google's smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: Yea thats why I was trying to get at...

Comment: But as far as I am aware, google shopping likes categories assigned in the URL

Comment: Yep, so many useless bypasses of Magento function to match some "Idee Fixe" often lead to "lead in the foot" syndrome which fix the imagined problem and leave you with a real problem.